# Code examples for a wallpaper app?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to write a C# app that runs like an overlay on the desktop wallpaper.  Similar to the way that desktop widgets or Rainmeter(rainmeter.net) runs; behind other apps but on top of the desktop wallpaper.

I cannot find any C# examples of this kind of behavior.  Can someone point to me to some code?

Here is an example of what I am interested in creating: http://jabz.us/uploaded_images/screenCaptureRainmeter.png

Comment: That style wouldn't work for everything, but it's pretty slick looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use WPF windows that are [borderless](http://learnwpf.com/Posts/Post.aspx?postId=e9cb689c-e6af-407a-b28c-d38f2f2f555c) (and therefore static, but you can move them again by using [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34738/Moving-a-WPF-Window-with-a-WindowStyle-of-None.aspx)), [transparent](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/johnbowen/archive/2007/06/20/20458.aspx) and [below all other windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181336/how-to-send-a-wpf-window-to-the-back)? You may have to poll each window under the rest every 100ms or so incase the user accidentally clicks it. I have made a little test with just some labels and it looks fine.

For example, use this code and poll the "below all other windows" method every so often.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="LearnWPF.BorderlessWindow" Height="200" Width="200" 
    WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="Transparent"
>
    <Border Padding="5" BorderBrush="#feca00" 
        BorderThickness="3" Width="150" Height="150">
        <TextBlock>Learn WPF!</TextBlock>
    </Border>
</Window>
```