# Don't show window on shell tray

Tags: c#, wpf, window

### I want to create a gadget. when opening windows they appear on the shell tray as:

[image]

how can I prevent a window from showing on that tray. I already know how to send a window to the back to make it appear as a gadget. I found that example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181336/how-to-send-a-wpf-window-to-the-back/1181764#1181764). It will be nice if that menu does not show up meanwhile the window is active and open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Window property `ShowInTaskbar` to restrict or allow your Window to appear in the taskbar.

Comment: Gah! Beat me by a couple seconds. :)