# Keep form in back of other windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I make a gaget form. It little big, so click on it when work in other windows, it fly to front of that windows. I want it keep in back all of time. Any solution? thanks for read.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181336/how-to-send-a-wpf-window-to-the-back and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527950/how-to-make-always-on-bottom-window - do you agree?

Comment: It not, it make form in back when load, not always. But, i found answer after click multiple link in it. Thanks. anwser is hook in there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365094/window-on-desktop . I dont like hook, but it work perfect.

Comment: A caution that the accepted/most votes answer in the link you suggested proposed making the window a child of the desktop without outlining why you shouldn't